Can Multiple Regression Output (coefficients, ratios, etc.) Be Given a Predictive Interpretation?
Generally speaking, regression output can be given a causal interpretation for typically one variable in the model (that is under the assumption of no unobserved confounding and this is not to speak of the potential need of marginal effects, etc.) (Westreich and Greenland 2013, Keele et al. 2019).
The most intuitive and conservative interpretation of regression output in my opinion is a descriptive interpretation. However, I often see people interpret several coefficients, ratios, etc. from multiple regression as "predictors" of the outcome. With existing machine learning tools available, is it fair to give any coefficient in the model a predictive interpretation? If you wanted to understand the raw predictive power of a given variable, would you not just iteratively run various bivariable regression models for each predictor and use some statistic to evaluate its predictive capacity? Why generate estimates adjusted for other variables if you are just interested in the predictive power of each predictor?
It seems to me like the practice of adjusting for other variables in a regression model is a causal endeavor that may be given a descriptive interpretation if identifying assumptions are not satisfied. But I am not sure of this.

I see that your question runs deeper than that, but I feel like it should be mentioned that regression models are the absolute vanilla tool for prediction (see about every other kaggle challenge and what feels like 80% of ML papers) - so clearly the answer seems to be a resounding "yes".
